# reading from stdin in one second intervals

Tags: ruby

I have two simple scripts, reader and writer:

`writer.rb`:

```
while true
  puts "hello!"
  $stdout.flush
  sleep 1
end
```

`reader.rb`:

```
while true
  puts "I read: #{$stdin.read}!"
  sleep 1
end
```

`writer.rb` continuously writes to stdout, and `reader.rb` continuously reads from stdin.

Now if I do this:

```
ruby writer.rb | ruby reader.rb
```

I would expect this to keep printing

```
I read: hello!
I read: hello!
I read: hello!
```

At one second intervals. But it just blocks without printing anything. How do I get it to print? I thought `writer.rb` was caching the output so I added `$stdout.flush`, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Better to use a message queue. Or `eventmachine` to add a periodic timer.

Comment: I was going to go with some kind of IPC communication, but I figured it was worth asking why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at the [documentation of `read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read), which states:

> If length is omitted or is nil, it reads until EOF

which in your case happens when the writer terminates, which is expected to be never. You might want to use `readline`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$stdin.gets` instead of `.read` as `.read` reads till EOF.

```
puts "I read: #{$stdin.read}!"
```

should be

```
puts "I read: #{$stdin.gets}!"
```

Note: This will include the newline character, so the output will be something like:

```
I read: hello!
!
I read: hello!
!
I read: hello!
!
```

If you don't want the trailing newline, use `$stdin.gets.chomp`

Output with `$stdin.gets.chomp`:

```
I read: hello!!
I read: hello!!
```